# Instagram PHP API: getTagMedia only works locally

Tags: php, api, tags, media, instagram

I'm working with the Instagram PHP API (https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) and I have used a solution I found which have been working perfectly (see @kexxcream 's answer for the solution here: [Get all photos from Instagram which have a specific hashtag with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182191/take-all-photos-from-instagram-who-have-the-specific-hashtag-with-php)) until now obviously.. I can only get it to work locally but not at my referred domain that I have put in at my Instagram app. I have no idea if it has to do with my domain-bindings; my company (like most companies) got a dev-server which I've then binded to my domain. Though this has not been a problem before when I've used this solution for grabbing an instagram feed.

Anyway, does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
        // Get class for Instagram
        // More examples here: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API
        require_once 'instagram.class.php';

        // Initialize class with client_id
        // Register at http://instagram.com/developer/ and replace client_id with your own
        $instagram = new Instagram('09b639fa2d2845d99d7c3c748f273b30');

        // Set keyword for #hashtag
        $tag = 'insta';

        // Get latest photos according to #hashtag keyword
        $media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag);

        // Set number of photos to show
        $limit = 8;

        // Show results
        // Using for loop will cause error if there are less photos than the limit
        foreach(array_slice($media->data, 0, $limit) as $data)
        {
            #print('<pre>'); print_r($data); print('</pre>');
            ?>
            <div class="insta-item">
                <a href="<?php echo $data->link; ?>" target="_blank">
                    <img src="<?php echo $data->images->standard_resolution->url; ?>" height="46px" width="46px" alt="Pic" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend you to check your Instagram parameters.

There's a known [issue](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/wiki/Local-development) about the usage on localhost of the api.

If this still doesn't work, try adding a limit to the number of image loaded:

```
$media = $instagram->getTagMedia($tag, 10);
```

Comment: That "known issue" link with the curl_setopt functions fixed the problem perfectly, thank you! Been trying to solve this for some hours now.. Another thing: do you have an idea how to include special characters like "åäö" when declaring the tag?

Comment: Try to use the entity number or the entity name of your special characters, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)'s a list where you can find the most common one.