# How can I search Instagram with hashtags via a URL?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

On both [Facebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) and [Twitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter), you can do a simple search of hashtags on these channels via a URL search, for example,
https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/myhashtag

Can you do the same with Instagram also? I can't seem to figure it out. I did find some API, but that's about all: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take all photos from Instagram who have the specific hashtag with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182191/take-all-photos-from-instagram-who-have-the-specific-hashtag-with-php)

Comment: The last link is (effectively) broken: It redirects to a generic page, *"Instagram Platform"*, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram

Answer (score 10):

This might be something that Instagram implemented after this question was originally asked, but this currently works:

```
http://instagram.com/explore/tags/yourhashtag
```

OR

```
http://instagram.com/tags/yourhashtag
```

The latter simply redirects to the former, but it's handy to have a shorter URL in some instances.

You'll find out more about how to customise Instagrams URLs by using endpoints on their [API documentation page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).

I'm not very familiar with how to use URL parameters and I'd be curious to know if anyone has found a way to filter via URL both by user and hashtag. Meaning that you show everything a specific user has posted with a specific hashtag. Many Instagram plugins allow you to do this at the same time, so one would hope it's possible via URL as well.

Comment: Is there any way to use multiple hashtags?

Answer (score 1):

> There is the instagram public API's tags section that can help you do
>   this. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/
>
> http://iconosquare.com/tag/ is another alternative

For example: http://iconosquare.com/tag/flowers

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/11182218/1085891