# Can I pull Instagram photos that use a specific hashtag?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to pull Instagram photos that use a specific hashtag? Does the latest API allow this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all photos from Instagram which have a specific hashtag with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182191/get-all-photos-from-instagram-which-have-a-specific-hashtag-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The Instagram public API's tag section will let you do this. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

Comment: @user7589227 any time =D. But I think that this question has already been asked as I have pointed above. I notice that your new. Please read the help section to know how to post better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Have a good day!

Comment: @Switch Not anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need an API to perform this kind of thing. 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Also, your question is really vague-this site is designed for specific programming questions.